# How to handle Docker Images with constantly updating dependencies?

Tags: docker

We have a system architecture as such:

```
Artifactory (stores Docker images)
Jenkins (builds software stack)
```

When a build is triggered Jenkins goes to artifactory to find a Docker image and run it as a container to build our software.

We create a Docker image which contains all the necessary dependencies for our software build process. Now every so often we have to update the dependencies but this takes up value storage on our Artifactory servers where we track our Docker images. Is there a way to have separate Docker images that eventually come together during the building of the software to form the final container? What we want to avoid is having a large monolithic Docker image that needs to be updated fairly frequently.

Comment: `What we want to avoid is having a large monolithic Docker image that needs to be updated fairly frequently.` - Docker images are rarely large monolithic blocks. An image is usually composed of many layers. If you have two images that mostly share the same set of layers they will not take up the full size, instead only the base, plus the differences from the base layers.

Comment: Is that true when the image tags are not the same?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no need to store the docker images.

Just create a Dockerfile for your image and put your dependencies inside it and let Jenkins build your images on the fly via docker build [...].
So you can have small build images for different purposes.

If your build depends on other build parts, you might push them to your Artifactory server and another build container can pull it from there.

Also take a look at [multi-staged](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) Dockerbuilds, which makes it easy, to reuse your images or to copy artifacts directly from parent images.

Hope this helps, TK